# How to pass sample weights to a mini-batch for training (Julia Flux)

Tags: julia, flux

As mentioned in the title, this is part of my code to train the model on a mini-batch for a single step.

```
    loss, grad = Flux.withgradient(modelDQN.evalParameters) do
        qEval = modelDQN.evalModel(evalInput)
        Flux.mse(qEval, qTarget)
    end
    Flux.update!(modelDQN.optimizer, modelDQN.evalParameters, grad)
```

Now I wanted to add a sample weights vector `ISWeights`(equal length to `qEval` and `qTarget`) to the training process to achieve the following function:
[image]

where for each sample I can assign a weight to adjust the total error and so to the gradient. How can I achieve this using Julia Flux? For better understanding, I enclose the `fit` function of Tensorflow Keras here, I expect `ISWeights` to work like `sample_weight` argument here.

```
Model.fit(
    x=None,
    y=None,
    batch_size=None,
    epochs=1,
    verbose="auto",
    callbacks=None,
    validation_split=0.0,
    validation_data=None,
    shuffle=True,
    class_weight=None,
    sample_weight=None, # equivalent to this argument here
    initial_epoch=0,
    steps_per_epoch=None,
    validation_steps=None,
    validation_batch_size=None,
    validation_freq=1,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you just want something like `weighted_mse(a,b,w) = sum(sqrt.(sum(abs2, a .- b; dims=1)) .* w') / length(a)` in place of `Flux.mse`? (Assuming `a, b` matrices, so that `w'` is along their batch dim.)

Comment: @mcabbott Thanks for your answer. I’m wondering if there is any build-in function that is more efficient or do I have to implement it myself?

Comment: This should be efficient. The built-in thing isn't very special: https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/da8ce81fcf923c9ee63a9d349d66972b44e4f7c1/src/losses/functions.jl#L47  Maybe I shouldn't have put a `sqrt` in mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that in the official docs there is a standard and concise way to implement the weighted mean for the error using built-in MSE.

```
loss(ŷ, y, agg=x->mean(w .* x))
```

Reference: [Loss Functions Flux](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/losses/)